# Appropriate way to store face embeddings. File system or database?

Tags: database, web-applications, filesystems, flask-sqlalchemy, face-recognition

I'm building a face recognition web app using Flask (verification task, i.e., compare to face embeddings, one from webcam and another from storage. Then, verify if those are the same person). Now, I face the problem that "Should I store registered face embeddings in file system or database system?".

Answer (score 0):

It will always depend on the size of this *embeds*. If it's represented by a Gaussian distribution of thousands of samples I wouldn't store it in a database since its size can grow too much.

A common solution to this problem, if you want to have a reference to the *embeds* in the database, is using a mixed approach: Store the results in a file, and save the path to this file in the database.

As a tip, if you proceed to implement this approach, don't store the absolute path of the images on the database, but a relative one, since it will give you flexibility on moving the files around the file-system without messing the data.

You can refer to [this complete answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787) to help you decide.